# PHP code to add a link to the configured default home page

Tags: 7, navigation

The default home page of a site can be configured in Home » Administration » Configuration » System » Site information.

I have a node instance (with PHP code text format) and I need to insert a link to the default home page of my site, knowing that it can be reconfigured later. In other words, I can't put a static link, I need to fetch info from Drupal (if possible).

How can I create such a link with a PHP code snippet? Is this possible?

**Solution**

I got away with:

```
<?php
    $ttmp = variable_get('site_frontpage', url());
    echo '<a href="/'.$ttmp.'">Home</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want programmatically get the value in your Site Configuration, then this works for me: `<?php print variable_get('site_frontpage', url()) ?>` although I'm not sure this will work in multilingual environment.

Comment: However I wonder why you would do this, since the solution you quote shows that this could be achieved by putting simply '/' as href - Drupal would resolve it internally to whatever is currently set as frontpage. I might be missing something though...